# Is there any way to zoom buttons in c#?

Tags: c#, button, resize

I created windows form with few buttons. Now i want that when cursor points to each button, button pop out or zoom and when cursor remove from that button, it will come in its normal size.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutrid.com)

Comment: I think win form doesn't support such graphic effects. Try WPF.

Comment: davioooh, it might not be as elegant as in WPF but you can easily do the same in Windows Forms.

Comment: @Joey I'm not an expert about WPF but I know it has some facilities for graphical effects like this... WinForm is very "basic" so you can use just workarounds to obtain a zoom effect... am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Could look similar to this:

```
Button.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(delegate(object Sender, EventArgs e) { Button.Size = new Size(Button.Size.Width + 50, Button.Size.Height + 50); } Button.Location = new Point(Button.Location.X - (50 / 2), Button.Location.Y - (50 / 2)});

Button.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(delegate(object Sender, EventArgs e) { Button.Size = new Size(Button.Size.Width - 50, Button.Size.Height - 50 }; Button.Location = new Point(Button.Location.X + (50 / 2), Button.Location.Y + (50 / 2)});

Button.GotFocus +=  new EventHandler(delegate(object Sender, EventArgs e) { Button.Size = new Size(Button.Size.Width + 50, Button.Size.Height + 50); } Button.Location = new Point(Button.Location.X - (50 / 2), Button.Location.Y - (50 / 2)});

Button.LostFocus += new EventHandler(delegate(object Sender, EventArgs e) { Button.Size = new Size(Button.Size.Width - 50, Button.Size.Height - 50 }; Button.Location = new Point(Button.Location.X + (50 / 2), Button.Location.Y + (50 / 2)});
```

You could also loop throught the "This.controls" event, and define each button, then add this event. This is scripting, you can do pretty much anything =)

Comment: This is the way it should work. But be careful. If you choose to large values for the zoom then it can happen that your zoomed-control overlays with another one.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button-size by code in the mouse-enter-event. and reset it in the mouse-leave-event.

Comment: Not only the size but also the position (if you don't want to zoom from the upper left). If the button is anchored or in a layout panel it gets more complicated, maybe.

Comment: if you increase the width by 20 then you have to changed the x-location of the control to the current value - 10. the same u have to do with the height and the y-location

Comment: Take a look at my post below. I gave an example with some code.

Answer (score 1):

ya u can change the size of button at mouse enter and leaving events OR create two images one 
is small and other large and change the image on these events.

Comment: How? Could you plz explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle both the MouseEnter/MouseLeave and the GotFocus/LostFocus events to account for keyboard navigation.

Effects like this are much easier in WPF applications. Perhaps you should consider creating a WPF app if you need visual effects. Check [Scale transform in xaml (in a controltemplate) on a button to perform a "zoom"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604152/scale-transform-in-xaml-in-a-controltemplate-on-a-button-to-perform-a-zoom) where a similar requirement is handled by scaling the button, in a manner that can be attached to any button you want, avoiding writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to be to use `SetBounds`. `Control.Scale` doesn't work well, as it assumes that you scale a complete window including all child controls and thus will always scale from the top left corner of the viewport (in this case the window client frame).

```
    Button b;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Hover me";
        b.Top = 100;
        b.Left = 100;
        b.Size = new Size(80, 30);

        this.Controls.Add(b);

        b.MouseEnter += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b.SetBounds(b.Left - 5, b.Top - 2, b.Width + 10, b.Height + 4);
        };
        b.MouseLeave += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b.SetBounds(b.Left + 5, b.Top + 2, b.Width - 10, b.Height - 4);
        };
    }
```